# How to dispatch an action when another synchronous action is complete in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an action that updates some search criteria in Redux. I'd like to immediately fetch some data from an API based on that local criteria. The problem is that although the search criteria action dispatch is synchronous, it will not complete before the search results dispatch begins.

In this example, the criteria will not be updated before the api call:

```
this.props.dispatch(updateLocalCriteria(someData));
this.props.dispatch(fetchApiResults(this.props.criteria))
```

Am I missing something obvious? I can think of a few hacky ways to handle this, but what is the best way? Should I set a flag when search criteria updates, and fetch results in `componentDidUpdate()` if the flag is true? Or should I make `updateLocalCriteria()` asynchronous just so I can chain `fetchApiResults()` in the promise chain?

**EDIT**

I think I've found my answer. I can get the current state within `fetchApiResults()`. Therefore, I can get the current search criteria before making the api call.

```
function fetchApiResults() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState();
        // fetch data and dispatch...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `updateLocalCriteria`, you probably already change one of the props of your reducer to the new value, I'll call it `criteria`.

What you could do instead is create another action let's say `updateCriteriaAndFetch` that will be called just like you did:

```
this.props.dispatch(updateCriteriaAndFetch(newCriteria))
```

That you will define basically like so

```
export const updateCriteriaAndFetch = criteria => dispatch => {
  dispatch(updateLocalCriteria(criteria))
  dispatch(fetchApiResults(criteria))
}
```

The second dispatch will even wait for your first synchronous update to be finished, even if you don't really need it because you already has access to it.

You can still do what you said, get the current state of your store, but it seems quite overkill to me, since you can simply pass it as a parameter or you action.

Comment: `updateLocalCriteria()` just updates one property of the criteria, but I want to send all the criteria to `fetchApiResults()`. I suppose I'd still need to get the current state within `updateCriteriaAndFetch()` before calling `fetchApiResults()`.

Comment: In this case yes indeed